# best practice to use (click) with multiple expressions in angular2

Tags: angular, click

I have to use multiple expressions on a button click in angular2.

one way is `(click)="expr1; expr2; expr3"`

Other way is declare a js method and perform all the expressions in a single method.

```
(click)="doMethod()"
```

in ts file:

```
doMethod(){
expr1;
expr2;
expr3;
}
```

Which is the best practice to use? please suggest.

Comment: Calling methods from the view is generally bad if you are creating a new instance of an object etc. But if they are just assignments to the existing variables, I don't think it will make a difference.

Comment: yeah they are just assignments to existing 7 variables. Shall i go ahead with (click)="expr1; expr2; expr3" this approach.

Comment: Why do you have 7 variables being assigned? That definitely needs abstracting, not for the sake of the template but for the sake of the program at large.

Comment: If there are 7 variables being assigned on a click, why not put them in an object (`{}`)? Also please format your code, as brief as it is.

Comment: i will have a object instead of multiple var assignments. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Are you mean call many expr?
You can try

```
(click)="doMethod(expr1, expr2, expr3)"
```

in ts file:

```
doMethod(expr1, expr2, expr3){
  //do something
}
```

Comment: He is asking which is preferred. Also, while it is fairly clear what you mean, the OP is using the term _expression_ differently. So in his example, `(click)=doMethod(expr1, exp2, exp3)` is not equivalent.